# Pass rails association data to angular view

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

In an angular view I want to show all instances of a model plus some fields from that models associated model. Nomination belongs_to User and User has_many Nominations. User has an archived boolean attribute which I need to pass to the angular view. Below is how the nomination data is currently passed to the angular app.

api - nominations_controller

```
def index
  render json: Nomination.all
end
```

For each nomination, I would like to include the archived attribute for the user which the nomination belongs to. In a rails view, I could access that attribute via Nomination.first.user.archived, for example. How do I pass that attribute as part of the json data? I've tried

```
def index
  render json: User.includes(:nominations).where.not(nominations: {user_id: nil})
end
```

Which gives me the users I want and the archived attribute and all its other associations, such as teams, but it is not passing the Nominations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.includes()` to include the data from the parent object.  Something like:

```
def index
  render json: Nomination.includes(:user)
end
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried that originally but Nomination is the child model of User. I've updated my question.

Comment: Looks like your solution below uses my answer to get it done, feel free to +1

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the creator of the api had overwritten the serializable_hash method in the User model so I had to add nominations to that method. Once I did that, this worked.

```
def index
  render json: User.includes(:nominations).where.not(nominations: {user_id: nil})
end
```

I have since refactored it to use a scope

```
def index
  render json: User.includes(:nominations).has_nominations
end
```

in user.rb

```
def self.has_nominations
  where.not(nominations: {user_id: nil})
end
```